# Extract all images out from each node in content type

Tags: 7, media

Every time a new node is published within a single content type, I wish to extract (not remove) all the images out from that node's body and save the URL(s) of the images in the database. I will then use the URLs to make a slideshow of the images on a separate node.

I have three questions:

1. Which hook runs right before a node is published?
2. What's the best way of saving those URLs in the database?
3. Which Drupal function do I use to retrieve those URLs from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which book runs right before a node is published?

- hook_node_update($node) The hook is invoked after the node is inserted/updated in the node table

> What's the best way of saving those URLs in the database?

- It totally depends upon your needs, Simply you will have to save in database in your own table(s).

> Which Drupal function do I use to retrieve those URLs?

- It is not clear from where you want to retrieve. Database or Node Body.

  - For database you need to focus on [Database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/group/database/7)
  - For Node body, you will have to parse some way e.g. [PHP Simple Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: For the third question, I meant retrieving the saved URLs from the database. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that. But thanks for the hook and the advice to save them to a separate database - I'll look into that.

Comment: The first question was *before* the node is saved so the hook is [hook_node_presave[(http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) also, the hook_node_update isn't called while you insert a node.